# How to use RDP and SSH on 1 ip address

Tags: windows-server-2008, centos

I have a home Verizon router setup and on which i run a couple websites.

I have all the ports open (21, 22, 80, etc.)

I would like to be able to RDP into the server at my home as well.

I can accomplish this by NATing my external IP to the internal IP of the server, however that will knock my Websites down.

Currently I have my websites setup on a Hyper-v, Centos.

My main server is the host for the virtual machines.

Anyone know how i might be able to accomplish RDP to my server, AND keep my web sever on the web and available via SSH

Answer (score 1):

Use SSH port forwarding:

ssh -L 8080:internalServerIP:3389 user@publicIP

This would allow you to RDP to localhost:8080 to reach your remote internalServer.

You can even change the SSH listening port from 22 (standard) to 443 to get past most firewalls. For Windows, Cygwin (or puTTY) is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure port forwarding on your router. From your question it seems like you have your public IP natted to a single internal IP (DMZ mode). You would need to change that to only forward the ports you need to the specific internal system. (e.g., 22 to the SSH server, 80 to the webserver, 3389 to the windows system)

Every router or firewall has a different way to do that, and without specifics on what model you have, I can't give exact instructions.

Comment: I only have one IP address which is the dynamic address that Verizon gives me.  When i NAT that address to my server IP "!92.168.1.2" and setup port forward to 3389 it works fine. However i can no longer hit my websites or SSH into my Centos Server 192.168.1.3. I have tried just hitting my server via IP , 3389 and that doesnt seem to see the server at all.

Comment: I'm suggesting that you forward port 3389 to one internal IP and 22, 80, 443, etc to another. Your router/firewall has to support that function. Most do. It sounds like you're using DMZ mode, which is not going to work. Again, without details on your firewall model, I can't give better instructions.